# Cant configure directly my .cert file .key into gretty ssl config

Tags: java, gradle, webserver, jetty, gretty

I have a authorized .cert file from popular CA and corresponding private key file(.key). How can I manually configure or import into gretty server?
I saw the steps which describes via keystore format . Is there any other direct import way like other web server does?

Answer (score 0):

The SSL/TLS layers in Java are implemented in Java, they don't use openssl or any other library that typically supports `.cert` and `.key` files.

Java uses the `keystore` format for all things related to security certificates, you'll have to create/import those .cert and .key files into a valid keystore file before you can use those certificates in a Java project that uses SSL/TLS.

Comment: Yes thanks. So now I already have a CA authorized cert and key file, should I need to import into keystore format or my CA provider can give as a required format?